# Android- Images on RecyclerView GridLayout are at the bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is my current code for `Gridlayout`:

```
image_list.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true));
```

When I do this, **all this images are lined at the bottom, not the top**. Anyway I could fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You have to set reverseLayout Boolean to false.

Comment: I am not getting you .Can you explain it briefly.?

Comment: Put your image pulling code for reference.

Comment: I am doing it through FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Answer (score 2):

**Set reverselayout to false**

```
 //Like this
 image_list.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
```

> Documentation :

```
 /**
 * @param context Current context, will be used to access resources.
 * @param spanCount The number of columns or rows in the grid
 * @param orientation Layout orientation. Should be {@link #HORIZONTAL} or {@link
 *                      #VERTICAL}.
 * @param reverseLayout When set to true, layouts from end to start.
 */
public GridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount, int orientation,
        boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    setSpanCount(spanCount);
}
```

Comment: If I set it to false, the gridlayout has the oldest pictures on the top, while the new ones are on the bottom. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: Need to sort array list to achieve it.

Comment: I'm pulling the images from Firebase, how would that be achievable?